# How to return Json Object from view to controller MVC4.

Tags: json

I have this script to extract form data and serialize to Json Object:

```
form = document.forms[0];
        $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };

        $(function () {
            form.submit(function () {
                result.append(JSON.stringify(form.serializeObject()));
                return false;
            });
        });
```

I want to put this on an html button and then send the object resulted in the controller.But how?
 The action will be an JSONResult() ? 
 How do i can do all this? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach onclick event on button.
Use jquery ajax call to post json to action in controller
Return a action result as json object.
Do whatever you want on sucess event of jquery ajax call procedure.

For details ask google!

Comment: Nice, thanks.. i understand now.. but.. what is the function to put onclik="" mouse event? I'm new in javascript and i need to know this..

Comment: <button id="btnClick" onclick="SendData();">ClickMe!</button> Next write javascript like this : function SendData(){ //fn body } . Altough this is common approach, for getting into standards you should just put button inside form for creating real post requests.